# A question related to Stone's Theorem on one-parameter unitary groups

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am currently reading up on Stone's Theorem on one-parameter unitary groups and I came across following claim in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups#cite_note-1):

> Consider the one-parameter family $(U_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ of unitary operators defined by $U_{t}:=e^{itA}$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then, $(U_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a strongly continuous one-parameter group. Moreover, A will be bounded if and only if the operator-valued mapping $t \mapsto U_{t}$ is continuous with the operator norm.

I can see why $(U_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ strongly continuous. However, I have been struggling to prove the second claim. That is, *A will be bounded if and only if the operator-valued mapping $t \mapsto U_{t}$ is continuous with respect to the operator norm.*

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the first theorem in Pazy's semigroups textbook.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you referring to Theorem 1.2 of Chapter-1?

Comment: That's the one! $\ $

Comment: I think your original question came from Hall's book, is that correct? If so, it's interesting, because while I would have suggested the approach in Pazy's book, but it seems that Hall had another solution in mind. I think it's somewhat clear what he's hinting at (in the literal hint), but I dont quite see how it would work.